# How to fill Text background color of android switch

Tags: android, android-widget

I am Switch view in android app. I need to change the background  color of Text "ON" and Text "OFF" dynamically.
Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Comment: I have no idea why your question has 2 upvotes and who would upvote it. Give us more information. Relevant bits of code and explain more about your situation and what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
android:switchTextAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"
```

xml styles:

```
<style name="SwitchTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/#xxxxxx</item>
</style>

setSwitchTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.SwitchTextAppearance);
```

Comment: But it doesnot change the background color of text . If just changes the color of text. I want the text background to be changed the way we see in settings.

Comment: then set android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
         android:track="@drawable/switch_bg" in your code

Comment: how to use android:thumb programatically. Android doesn't provide any option to programatically set it in API 14.

Comment: take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#setThumbResource(int)